# How would we calculate the answer to this simple counting game problem?

Tags: contest-math

I am conscious of the fact that this question is very elementary, but I have no apparent idea as to how one intends to go about it. If someone could kindly provide a layman possessing the soul of myself some mathematical intuition, it would be appreciated greatly.

Consider the following counting game, in which Person A will say the number 1, then Person B states the next two numbers (i.e. 2 and 3), Person C shall say the next three numbers, prior to the moment when Person A states the next four numbers. This process continues to proceed in a rotation, until the number googleplexian is obtained. The question I wish to pose is: **Out of Person A, B and C, who states the last number?**

Comment: Hint:  The total number of numbers spoken by the trio after $n$ terms is the $n^{th}$ triangular number, $\frac {n(n+1)}2$.  though, of course, the extreme size of the number involved might make the computation  difficult.

Comment: yes if you can solve for n(n+1)/2 = googolplex, then divide it by 3 and the modulo number says it.

Comment: Hint: $100\equiv1\mod3\implies10^{100}\equiv1^{100}=1\mod3$ et cetera.

Comment: @user29418 What's the remainder mod $3$ of the sum of the first half a googol digits of $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Magma you know very well that it's not possible to do a clever manipulation. your question is ill-posed.